RollupError: [type] is not exported by [file]
I followed this guide to make a UI library: https://dev.to/receter/how-to-create-a-react-component-library-using-vites-library-mode-4lma
When I try to build i get this error on my interfaces: RollupError: [type] is not exported by [file]
